# {'date': ['Это поле не может иметь значение NULL.']}

Tags: python-3.x, django

Пишу блог на wagtail при добавлении страницы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]вот такая ошибка выскакивает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот структура проекта:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать, `date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)`, если указывать дату публикации не обязательно. Или

```
from datetime import date
date = models.DateField("Date", default=date.today)
```

для добавления даты создания публикации.

Ссылки на похожие вопросы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351619/how-to-make-djangos-datetimefield-optional
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029295/django-datefield-default-options

Comment: Спасибо помогло 
from datetime import date
date = models.DateField("Date", default=date.today)